# Fetch only first alphabet word from column in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, split, position, space

I have a column "Name" in postgresql. I need to fetch only alphabets from it. It should fetch only first word before space and should only fetch alphabets. Below is the input and expected output screenshot :

[image]

Below is the sql fiddle for it :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80018/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [***SUBSTRING***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function with regular expression to extract matched substring:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, '^[a-zA-Z]+') FROM test1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80018/3/0